# Validation Message

Tags: asp.net-mvc

this is my Form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("RepR", "Agence", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "search_form" })) { %>
            <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
            <%: Html.Hidden("to", Model.mailc) %>
           <p>
            Sujet : <br />
            <%: Html.TextBox("sub")%> 

            <br />
             Message : <br />
            <%: Html.TextArea("msg")%> 

           </p>
            <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" class="button"/>
            <% } %>
```

It works so fine, but I want to add some validation message (I can't use Model because this form is on page where I use an another model).
I already tried with this ways but dosn't works

```
<%: Html.ValidationMessage("sub","Requiered field") %>
```

any idea here on what i should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use partial view and strongly type Model. then call this partial View in main View. it is a simple and efficient

Other solution is add ModelState.AddModelError("Field Name", "Error Message") but this work only server side.

if you want client side Validation you can use JQuery.valid methode